# Hadoop/Hive - Split a single row into multiple rows and store to a new table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, sql-insert, create-table

Currently, I solve my initial problem with this topic: Hadoop/Hive - Split a single row into multiple rows and store to a new table.

Does anyone have a clue how to create a new table with the grouped subs?

```
ID  Subs
1   deep-learning, machine-learning, python
2   java, c++, python, javascript
```

with the code below I get the return I'm looking for but could not figure out how to save the output into a new table

```
use demoDB 
Select id_main , topic_tag from demoTable
lateral view explode (split(topic_tag , ',')) topic_tag as topic
```

Thanks
Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hive, you can use `create ... as select ...`:

```
create table newtable as
select id_main, topic_tag 
from demoTable
lateral view explode (split(topic_tag , ',')) topic_tag as topic
```

This creates a new table and initiates its content from the resultset of the query. If the new table exists already, then use `insert ... select` instead:

```
insert into newtable (id_main, topic_tag)
select id_main, topic_tag 
from demoTable
lateral view explode (split(topic_tag , ',')) topic_tag as topic
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick answer and the explanation!